# Does a static electric field act continuously?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-fields

Electromagnetic radiation is emitted and absorbed in discrete units, photons.
One photon's energy is described by the well known $E = hf$ formula.

Now, if you a have static electric field that doesn't oscillate or other, then we can say $f = 0$. So the photon energy is zero.

Does this mean a static electric field accelerates charges continuously and not in a series of discrete kicks?

Comment: Are you asking about the way quantum electrodynamics describes a static field (e.g. the role of virtual photons) or about the way a charge accelerating due to a static field emits (real) photons? Or something else?

Comment: @JohnRennie I'm confused, what's the difference? I thought about real photons...

Comment: Strictly speaking there is no such thing as a static field, not even in the classical picture. That's an abstraction that excludes the finite time any field can exist.

Comment: Assuming an effectively (*pace* CuriousOne :-) static external field, and an electron accelerating in that field, then the electron doesn't emit photons at set intervals with corresponding jerks in its motion. The electron goes into a superposition of the electron and emitted photons. This superposition only collapses into an observed electron and observed photon when something collapses the superposition.

Comment: That's one way of looking at it, but I think the collapse picture is somewhat misleading in QFT, especially in case of photons which are escaping at the speed of light from the interaction point and the electron will, inevitably interact with the thermal radiation field. So unless we are talking about an experiment in free space that is kept at very low temperature, the "collapse" is inevitably given by decoherence.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Agreed. There remains the question of what exactly I would pick up on my EM detector, which seems mildly interesting...

Comment: @JohnRennie: I think that is a very interesting question, indeed. There is a line of thought that electrons are actually constantly subjected to insane accelerations due to these interactions... which, of course is the consequence of a semi-classical analysis of a non-classical system. Personally I have this religious belief that nature is actually lazy and does as little as possible to achieve the results that we get to see. But that, of course, is a religious belief. I am just glad I am allowed to have them around here. :-)

Answer (score -1):

It is really true that the electric field of an electron does not oscillate. It is a static field. If you accelerate an electron - and this one do exclusively by the help of an EM field - the electron absorbs photons and emits photons. And photons have an oscillating electric and magnetic field. However, this is not relevant for most macroscopic processes.

Radio waves, where a large number of electrons are accelerated in a periodically antenna rod, form a periodically oscillating electric and magnetic field which one can observe.